# How to use .cer format certificate in curl cli based browser?

Tags: sockets, curl, proxy, http2, zap

I got only .cer format certificate from the OWASP ZAP 2.5.0 but the curl which I am using as CLI browser requires .key and/or .pem formats as well. How can I obtain that as I have only cer file.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions on this page: http://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-to-convert-a-cer-file-in-pem

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I got the following error: unable to load certificate
140448620088856:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1199:
140448620088856:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:374:Type=X509

Comment: You could do it the other way around - create your own fake root CA cert in pem format then import that into ZAP. The help gives an example of this - its actually the skipfish cert :)